# Relative path on fs.watchfile using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this method to read data from the file when it changes. I restructured my project and now the data isn't read anymore.

```
fs.watchFile("???", (curr, prev) => {
    console.log("Änderung auf Data.json");
    fs.readFile("Data.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
        widgets = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Daten ausgelesen" );
        io.emit("dataUpdate", {widgets});
    });   
});
```

You can see my file paths here. The method above is in client.js and I want to refer to Data.json.

[image: Picture of my files]

I tried:
"../Data.json" and 
"/Server/Data.json"

Thanks for your help!

PS.: I know that there are threads explaining relative paths, but I still couldn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__dirname` https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

example:

```js
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'data.json');
```